# How to prevent Webpack from removing other files in output path?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, webpack-3

Let's say I compile some JS assets to dist/static/js:

```
output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
        chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js'),
    },
```

Before running `npm run build` I create one file in /dist/, /static/ and /js/.

After running `npm run build` **this file was removed**. The one created in /static/ and /js/ is gone. How can I prevent it?

I'm using Vue.js/Webpack boilerplate:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/17ed63b1b3a0eaaebd3f593c08c32107a7cb7e01/template/build/build.js

You can see that a package called `rimraf` is being imported:

```
const rm = require('rimraf')
```

This package is responsible for clearing out your `assetsRoot` and `assetsSubDirectory`. This is a good thing because usually when you re-run your build process from nothing, you want a clean slate to begin with.

I would advise you not to disable this but rather put your file in another directory or let your Javascript generate your file since the removal takes places before the compilation.